# In EditText want Cursor position at end of the string

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am facing some issue regarding to Cursor position in EditText Android, in my case when app open then first login screen shows and automatically keyboard open, but the cursor position is at start of the string I want to shift that cursor position at end of the string, for that I use 
`username.setSelection(username.getText().length());`

this but this is not working in xamarin,
please suggest me what I use in Xamarin and Mvvmcross for this

thank you

Comment: Set `edittext.length()` .

Comment: No not for hint, actually I store username of last login user, so that when they come for login they see there username but cursor shows in wrong position

Answer (score 2):

```
myEditText.setText("MyUsername");
myEditText.setSelection(myEditText.length());
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but please tell me the answer in full form means with initializes of pos and all, I am new on coding